# How to delete all records of a particular table when user logout in laravel5.3?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5.3

I wanted to delete all the records from the particular table when user logout in laravel 5.3 if it is possible? I am trying to do like the following but i get an error as **BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method truncate does not exist.** How should i do that?

```
 public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();
        Store_seat::all()->truncate();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling the truncate method directly on the model class

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->flush();

        $request->session()->regenerate();
        Store_seat::truncate();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why this is happening? for education purposes